# Conditional insert xquery failing with error "unexpected insert, expecting else"

Tags: xquery, sedna

I am trying to execute the xquery on Sedna database to conditionally update the container, as below

```
if(fn:exists(doc("blog")/entries/entry[@active="1" and @id="1"]/comments)) then
UPDATE insert <comment active="1"><name>sunil.s</name><email>suni.l.s@gmail.com</email><desc>desbbh</desc></comment> into doc("blog")/entries/entry[@active="1" and @id="1"]/comments
else
UPDATE insert <comments><comment active="1"><name>sunil.s</name><email>sunil.s@gmail.com</email><desc>sdd</desc></comment></comments> into doc("blog")/entries/entry[@active="1" and @id="1"]
```

But this query always failing with below error

> SEDNA Message: ERROR XPST0003 It is a static error if an expression is
>   not a valid instance of the grammar defined in A.1 EBNF. Details: at
>   (2:8), syntax error, unexpected insert, expecting else

The error indicate that it is expecting `else` instead of `insert` in the second line.

Can someone please help me understand problem with the query and possible fix?

Answer (score 0):

Your query assumes the existence of an expression with syntax like

```
UPDATE insert expr into expr
```

There is no such expression in XQuery (or the XQuery Update Facility). Instead, it appears to be a non-standard syntax supported by Sedna.

However, the documentation (http://www.sedna.org/progguide/ProgGuidesu6.html#x12-430002.3) refers to it as a "statement", not an "expression", suggesting that it must be the 'top-level' (outermost) construct in your query.

To accomplish this, you could rewrite your query as:

```
UPDATE
insert
    if ... then <comment>...</comment> else <comments>...</comments>
into
    if ... then doc("blog")/.../comments else doc("blog")/...
```

Unfortunately, this repeats the 'if' condition; it's not clear whether Sedna provides a syntax for factoring that out, e.g.

```
UPDATE
let $c := ...
insert
    if $c then <comment>...</comment> else <comments>...</comments>
into
    if $c then doc("blog")/.../comments else doc("blog")/...
```